# Evaluate the maclaurin series from $0$ to $1.5$ with an error less than 0.0001

Tags: calculus, power-series

The original function is 
$$ f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$
finding the series expression of that function results in

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!} $$
Then integrating that series expression we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-x^{2n+2}}{(n+1)!}$$

So if I want to find when the value of the above Maclaurin sum when it is less than $0.001$ I just keep increasing the $n^{th}$ terms till I get an answer which i found to be when $n=9$ and the value $0.0000311$. Is this the correct way of solving it or is there a easier way?

Comment: You might double check your integration; it isn't quite right.

Comment: @Clayton Should the $-x$ instead become a $(-1)^n$?

Comment: The integral of $(x^2)^n$ is not $\frac{(x^2)^{n+1}}{n+1}$ :)

Comment: @Clayton ok so i redid my work and got $\frac{(-1)^n n^{2n+1}}{(n+1)n!}$

Comment: That is closer. I think you have a small typo (the $n^{2n+1}$ should be $x^{2n+1}$). The denominator doesn't reflect the new exponent, though (you are dividing by $n+1$ but your exponent is $2n+1$)...

Comment: @Clayton yeah sorry about the typo, Im running on caffeine and adrenaline right now.

Comment: In addition to the correction that Clayton has pointed (which you should edit the post to reflect the fix - particularly that last sentence, whose significance I'm not sure if you caught), it is unclear to me what you are doing in this calcuation. Do you mean that you want to find the value of $n$ so that if $-0.001 < x < 0.001$, then the sum of the first $n$ terms is guaranteed to be within $0.0001$ of the full value of the function? If so, you need to use one of the known error estimates for Taylor series. simply finding a term less than your error isn't enough. The tail could sum higher.